# duplicate a row and change a value of a column to the duplicate row

Tags: python, dataframe

I need your help What I am looking for is to obtain the table below starting from the table above.

```
Date   ID     Typol1   Facial#1   Facial#2 Typol2

april  426     COR      1000        500    LAR
may    419     LAR      5000        100    COR
```

```
Date   ID     Typol   Facial

abril  426     COR      1000  
abril  426     LAR      500  
may    426     LAR      5000  
may    426     COR      100
```

thanks

Comment: pd.concat and df.groupby will do. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how it would be

Comment: take a look at this function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Comment: I think you wanted  419 as ID of 3rd and 4th row

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['april','may'],
                'id':[426,419],
                'typol1':['COR','LOR'],
                'facial1':[1000,5000],
                'facial2':[500,100],
                'typol2':["LAR",'COR']})
```

change columns names

```
df.columns=['Date','Id','typo','facial','facial','typo']
```

concate data frame like that

```
df=pd.concat([df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]],df.iloc[:,[0,1,4,5]]])
```

output

```
    Date     Id    typo   facial
0   april   426     COR    1000
1   may     419     LOR    5000
0   april   426     LAR    500
1   may     419     COR    100
```